# Filtering out duplicate subsequent records in a SELECT

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands, window-functions

**(PostgreSQL 8.4)** 
Table "trackingMessages" stores tracking events between mobile devices (tm_nl_mobileid) and fixed devices (tm_nl_fixedId).

```
CREATE TABLE trackingMessages
(
  tm_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,           -- PK
  tm_nl_mobileId INTEGER,             -- FK to mobile
  tm_nl_fixedId INTEGER,              -- FK to fixed
  tm_date INTEGER,                    -- Network time
  tm_messageType INTEGER,             -- 0=disconnect, 1=connect
  CONSTRAINT tm_unique_row
    UNIQUE (tm_nl_mobileId, tm_nl_fixedId, tm_date, tm_messageType)
);
```

Problem here is that it's possible that the same mobile will connect to the same fixed twice (or more times) subsequently. I don't want to see the subsequent ones, but it's OK to see a mobile connected to a same fixed at a later date, provided there was a connection to a different fixed in between.

I think I'm close but not quite. I've been using the following CTE (found here on Stack Overflow)

```
WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT tm_nl_fixedid, tm_date, Row_number() OVER (
    partition BY tm_nl_fixedid
    ORDER BY tm_date ASC
  ) RN 
  FROM   trackingMessages
) 
SELECT * FROM cte 
  WHERE tm_nl_mobileid = 150 AND tm_messagetype = 1
  ORDER BY tm_date;
```

Gives me the following results

```
32;1316538756;1
21;1316539069;1
32;1316539194;2
32;1316539221;3
21;1316539235;2
```

The problem here is that the last column should be 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, because that third "32" is in fact a duplicate tracking event (twice in a row at the same fixed) and that last connection to "21" is OK because "32" was in between.

**Please don't suggest a cursor,** this is what I am currently trying to move away from. The cursor solution does work, but it's too slow given the amount of records I have to deal with. I'd much rather fix the CTE and only select where `RN = 1` ... unless you have a better idea!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you're not that close because `row_number()` cannot track sequences by two groups at the same time. `PARTITION BY tm_nl_fixedid ORDER BY date RESTART ON GAP` does not exist, there's no such thing.

Itzik Ben-Gan has a solution for the islands and gaps problem you are facing (several solutions, actually). The idea is to order rows by the main criteria (date) and then by partitioning criteria + main criteria. Difference between ordinals will remain the same as they belong to the same partitioning criteria and date series.

```
with cte as
(
  select *,
      -- While order by date and order by something-else, date
      -- run along, they belong to the same sequence
         row_number() over (order by tm_date)
       - row_number() over (order by tm_nl_fixedid, tm_date) grp
    from trackingMessages
)
select *,
    -- Now we can get ordinal number grouped by each sequence
       row_number() over (partition by tm_nl_fixedid, grp
                          order by tm_date) rn
  from cte
 order by tm_date
```

[Here is Sql Fiddle with example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/4cd20/5).

[And here is chapter 5 of Sql Server MVP Deep Dives with several solutions to islands and gaps problem](http://www.manning.com/nielsen/SampleChapter5.pdf).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! +1 for explaining the concept and +inf for the solution.

Answer (score 3):

This should be simpler with the [window function `lag()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE):

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *
         ,lag(tm_nl_fixedId) OVER (PARTITION BY tm_nl_mobileId
                                   ORDER BY tm_date) AS last_fixed
   FROM   trackingmessages
   )
SELECT *
FROM   cte
WHERE  last_fixed IS DISTINCT FROM tm_nl_fixedId
ORDER  BY tm_date
```

#### Explain

- In the CTE, `lag()` gets the last fixed device to which a mobile connected (`NULL` for the first row per mobile - that's why I use `IS DISTINCT FROM` later, see a different approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12467777/939860)).
- Then simply exclude all rows where the last fixed device was the same as this one, thereby excluding all "subsequent ones". All done.

Comment: This is... exactly twice as fast when run against 8 million records. Why?

Comment: @denpanosekai: This only needs one pass with one sort order for one window function + 1 final sort. Nikola's solution has three window functions on different windows + 1 final sort. Factor 2 is not surprising. `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` may tell you more.