# Detect SQL island over multiple parameters and conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands

**(PostgreSQL 8.4)** I got a great introduction to SQL gaps-and-islands [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451489/filtering-out-duplicate-subsequent-records-in-a-select) but I still have a question. Many island detection CTEs are based on a running order of a timestamp and some flag which breaks the sequence when it changes. But what if the "break" condition is a little more complex?

```
CREATE TABLE T1
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  val INT,   -- some device
  status INT -- 0=OFF, 1=ON
);

INSERT INTO T1 (val, status) VALUES (10, 1);
INSERT INTO T1 (val, status) VALUES (10, 0);
INSERT INTO T1 (val, status) VALUES (11, 1);
INSERT INTO T1 (val, status) VALUES (11, 1);
INSERT INTO T1 (val, status) VALUES (10, 0);
INSERT INTO T1 (val, status) VALUES (12, 1);
INSERT INTO T1 (val, status) VALUES (13, 1);
INSERT INTO T1 (val, status) VALUES (13, 0);
INSERT INTO T1 (val, status) VALUES (13, 1);
```

In this case, `val` represents a device, and `status` is either `ON` or `OFF`. I want to select records `1`, `3`, `6`, `7` and `9` with the following logic.

1. #10 turns ON -- OK, new sequence, include in SELECT
2. #10 turns OFF -- ends sequence properly, ignore row
3. #11 turns ON -- OK, new sequence, include in SELECT
4. #11 turns ON -- duplicate, ignore row
5. #10 turns OFF -- #10 wasn't ON, ignore
6. #12 turns ON -- OK, implicitly turns OFF #11, include in SELECT
7. #13 turns ON -- OK, implicitly turns OFF #12, include in SELECT
8. #13 turns OFF -- ends sequence properly, ignore row
9. #13 turns ON -- OK, new sequence, include in SELECT

Basically, only one device can be ON at a time, and the "break" condition is that:

- new.val = running.val AND new.status = 0
- new.val <> running.val AND new.status = 1

I'm looking for something in the form of a CTE, *no cursors please*.

Comment: Given the rows you want, that first condition is noise.  You don't appear to be interested in the `OFF` rows at all.

Comment: Added two extra rows (8, 9) along with explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer for updated question

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT *
         ,lag(val, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY status ORDER BY id) last_val
         ,lag(status) OVER (PARTITION BY val ORDER BY id) last_status
   FROM   t1
   ) x
WHERE  status = 1
AND    (last_val <> val OR last_status = 0)
```

#### How?

Same as before, but this time combine two window functions. Switching on a device qualifies if ..
1. the last device switched on was a *different* one.
2. or the same device has been switched *off* in its last entry. The corner case with `NULL` for the first row of the partition is irrelevant, because then the row already qualified in *1.*

---

### Answer for original version of question.

If your I understand your task correctly, this simple query does the job:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT *
         ,lag(val, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY id) last_on
   FROM   t1
   WHERE  status = 1
   ) x
WHERE  last_on <> val
```

Returns rows 1, 3, 6, 7 as requested.

#### How?

The subquery ignores all switching off, as that is just noise, according to your description. Leaves entries where a device is switched on. Among those, only those entries are disqualified, where the same device was on already (the last entry switching on). Use the [window function `lag()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) for that. In particular I provide `0` as default to cover the special case of the first row - assuming that there is no device with `val = 0`.
If there is, pick another impossible number.
If no number is impossible, leave the special case as `NULL` with `lag(val) OVER ...` and in the outer query check with:

```
WHERE last_on IS DISTINCT FROM val
```

Comment: That does work great, but I was missing an example to illustrate why I think status is important. Consider the extra two rows, which add an OFF from 13, then another ON. The same device twice in a row, which lag ignores (the 9th row needs to be picked up)

Comment: @Jeff: I added another solution. FYI, if you have updates for your question that would invalidate existing answers written in good faith, the recommended way is to *start a new question*. We may just roll back such edits. I added a new answer this once.